# Replace character "-"on cells with date format

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace "-" character by "." inside cells that contain date information.

With the code below, this is obtained in cells with text format, but not with date:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _ 
 What:="-", Replacement:=".", _ 
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

I can I do this but to cells with date format?

Comment: No, you can't set cell format condition in search. You will have to do this in a loop for each cell individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm.dd.yyyy;@"
End With
```

Leave the dates as dates that you can calculate against rather than converting them to text that are useless beyond a visual representation of an actual date.